# REDIS: redis in python does not return anything

Tags: python, pandas, redis

I'm trying to use redis to communicate with an API (Mailchimp) and save the results of the query to a csv file; but the function is neither saving the csv file nor returning any error. What am I missing?

This is my bg function:

```
def mailchimp_get_subscribed():

    config = mailchimp_config()
    path_params = 'lists' + '/xxxxxxxxx' + '/members'
    endpoint = urlparse.urljoin(config.api_root, path_params)
    query_params = {'fields': 'members.email_address', 'count': 10, 'offset': 0}

    data = requests.get(endpoint, auth=('apikey', config.apikey), params=query_params, verify=False).text
    data = json.loads(data)
    df = json_normalize(data['members'])
    df.to_csv('existing.csv')

    return df
```

And this is my main.py:

```
from rq import Queue
from redis import Redis
from mailchimp_get_subscribed import mailchimp_get_subscribed

# Tell RQ what Redis connection to use
redis_conn = Redis()
q = Queue(connection=redis_conn) # no args implies the default queue

# Delay execution of mailchimp_get_subscribed
job = q.enqueue(mailchimp_get_subscribed)
print(job.result)
time.sleep(5)
print(job.result)
```

This is the output:

```
runfile('/path/main.py', wdir='/path')
Reloaded modules: mailchimp_get_subscribed, mailchimp_config
None
None
```

Although it takes a milliseconds for the api to respond, my main.py is  returning neither the df nor is saving the csv file. I've tried executing mailchimp_get_subscribed() and it saves the csv correctly on the current path, so the function is working properly when its not being executed by redis.

What am I missing?

In adition... this is the log shown by redis-cli monitor:

```
1497331842.335658 [0 [::1]:59600] "MULTI"
1497331842.335722 [0 [::1]:59600] "SADD" "rq:queues" "rq:queue:default"
1497331842.335762 [0 [::1]:59600] "HSET" "rq:job:afe583b0-82e1-45ae-830b-9564faaa932e" "status" "queued"
1497331842.335776 [0 [::1]:59600] "HMSET" "rq:job:afe583b0-82e1-45ae-830b-9564faaa932e" "timeout" "180" "description" "mailchimp_get_subscribed.mailchimp_get_subscribed()" "data" "\x80\x04\x95<\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x8c1mailchimp_get_subscribed.mailchimp_get_subscribed\x94N)}\x94t\x94." "status" "queued" "enqueued_at" "2017-06-13T05:30:42Z" "created_at" "2017-06-13T05:30:42Z" "origin" "default"
1497331842.335827 [0 [::1]:59600] "RPUSH" "rq:queue:default" "afe583b0-82e1-45ae-830b-9564faaa932e"
1497331842.335862 [0 [::1]:59600] "EXEC"
1497331842.336224 [0 [::1]:59600] "HGET" "rq:job:afe583b0-82e1-45ae-830b-9564faaa932e" "result"
1497331847.342004 [0 [::1]:59600] "HGET" "rq:job:afe583b0-82e1-45ae-830b-9564faaa932e" "result"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is I hadn't started the worker!

Answer (score 1):

**Bingo.. I Got the issue**

You are setting Hash using command :

```
"HMSET" "rq:job:afe583b0-82e1-45ae-830b-9564faaa932e" "timeout" "180" "description" "mailchimp_get_subscribed.mailchimp_get_subscribed()" "data" "\x80\x04\x95<\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x8c1mailchimp_get_subscribed.mailchimp_get_subscribed\x94N)}\x94t\x94." "status" "queued" "enqueued_at" "2017-06-13T05:30:42Z" "created_at" "2017-06-13T05:30:42Z" "origin" "default"
```

If I get data of : `rq:job:afe583b0-82e1-45ae-830b-9564faaa932e` as below :

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL rq:job:afe583b0-82e1-45ae-830b-9564faaa932e
 1) "data"
 2) "\x80\x04\x95<\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x8c1mailchimp_get_subscribed.mailchimp_get_subscribed\x94N)}\x94t\x94."
 3) "description"
 4) "mailchimp_get_subscribed.mailchimp_get_subscribed()"
 5) "origin"
 6) "default"
 7) "enqueued_at"
 8) "2017-06-13T05:30:42Z"
 9) "timeout"
10) "180"
11) "created_at"
12) "2017-06-13T05:30:42Z"
13) "status"
14) "queued"
```

And you are trying to Get Hash data using :

```
"HGET" "rq:job:afe583b0-82e1-45ae-830b-9564faaa932e" "result"
```

**But THERE IS NO ELEMENT CALLED `result` IN YOUR HASH**

So that's why you are getting `blank` or `null` as result.

Try Below Code to Fix :

```
print(job.description)
```

OR

```
print(job.enqueued_at)
```